# Add margins in between columns of images?

Tags: html, css

I want a margin of 5px in between my three columns of images, but every time I add the margin, the third column goes down below the first two. I've tried decreasing the width of the columns to 30%, but then they aren't perfectly in the middle. How can I solve this?

html:

```
<div class="rows">
        <div class="column">
          <img src="https://testcreative.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Test-Twitter-Icon.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img src="https://testcreative.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Test-Twitter-Icon.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img src="https://testcreative.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Test-Twitter-Icon.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
```

css:

```
.rows {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  margin: 5px;
}

.column img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: wrapping item on divs is not always needed, you could've just added the class .column directly on the images.

Comment: I'm going to add many more images to each column so I thought it would be easier to just add .column once to the div rather than to every pic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with `calc()` like

```
.column {
  float: left;
  width: calc(33.33% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
}
```